# Counting the occurrence of characters of a string, and then substituting them with ( or ) dependant on count logic

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I need to get the string passed to the function to be split in to characters, then if the count of characters is equal to 1 in that word output a ( symbol, else ) my first Code Wars project. I can split the string into characters but I can't get the push method to work on the new array output, grabbed the `count[str] ? count[str]++ : count[str] = 1;` code from here.

```js
  function duplicateEncode(word){ 
    for (i=0; i < word.length; i++){
      var count = 0;
     
      word.split("").forEach(function(str) {    
         count[str] ? count[str]++ : count[str] = 1;
         
         if (count ==1){
            output.push["("];
         } else{
            output.push[")"];
         }
         console.log(output);
      });
    } 
  }

  duplicateEncode("din")
  duplicateEncode("recede")
  duplicateEncode("Success")
  duplicateEncode("(( @")
```

Comment: I don't exactly understand the required output can you add more clarification.

Comment: Sorry yeah basically if we take the first string "din" as an example we pass that to the duplicateEncode function which needs to count the occurance of each character in this string,if it equals 1 then we output ( else ) so the final output for the "din" string would be ))) as each character only occurs once in the string, I have tried to split the string and count the characters,but I am struggling to create an output array I can call at the end which will contain ))) characters as an example to output to console. Kind regards Jon

Answer (score 0):

first count each charcter Occurance, then map on the word again to compare
OccuranceCount and replace with encode character

```js
function duplicateEncode(word){
  characterOccurance = {} // will be {"char": "number of occurance"}

  word.split('').forEach(char => {
     if(characterOccurance[char]){ // if exist 
       characterOccurance[char] += 1; // increase the occurance count
     }else{
       characterOccurance[char] = 1;// set occurance to one
     }
  })

  let output = word.split('').map(
                    char => characterOccurance[char] == 1 ? ')' :'(' 
                    ).join('');
  return output;

}
```